# Does React have component names for built-in components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## Background

In React you can use a variable for a component constructor, like `ComponentToRender` in the code below.

```
import { Badger, Mushroom } from './components';

const renderBadger = true;

const Snake = () => {
    const ComponentToRender = renderBadger ? Badger : Mushroom;
    return <ComponentToRender />;
};
```

Here, I have a condition (`renderBadger`) and I choose the type of `ComponentToRender` based on that condition. Then I construct an instance of the appropriate component (either `Badger` or `Mushroom`) using JSX.

## Question

What should I do if I want to choose between `Badger` and a normal basic HTML `button`? i.e. fill in the blank below with the component name of a normal button.

```
const ComponentToRender = renderBadger ? Badger : ________;
```

## Temporary Workaround

I know I can achieve this with `React.createElement` (see below), but I would prefer to find out how to do this with JSX if possible.

```
const elementName = renderBadger ? Badger : 'button';

return React.createElement(elementName);
```

## Alternative Solution

I also realize that I could create a no-op wrapper `<button>` component, like this:

```
const Button = (
    props: React.PropsWithChildren<
        React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
    >,
) => {
    const { children, ...rest } = props;
    return (
        <button {...rest} type='button'>
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};
```

but I don't really want to introduce a bunch of pointless wrappers.

Comment: You should just be able to put the string `button` in there and it will work. [Proof](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-npsgor). `<ComponentToRender />` is the same as `React.createElement(ComponentToRender)`, which can take either a component function, or a string for vanilla HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, because I now see that that is normally possible. However, it didn't work when I tried it _specifically because_ I am using `<Link>` from React Router. When I use `const Element = condition ? Link : 'button'` and then try to create `<Element>`, I get an error. I am updating the question to include the example and error.

Comment: @AndyRay Actually I think this is a different issue, so I'm going to ask a new question. If you want to post your response as an answer, I will accept it here since it answers the question.

Comment: I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76425538/4476484) specifically about the `<Link>` element and the TS types associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AndyRay for the comment. You can still use the string version in the JSX constructor and it will work fine.

```
const ComponentToRender = renderBadger ? Badger : 'button';
```

For more information about what went wrong, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425538/why-does-the-react-router-link-component-not-accept-children-when-used-as-a-vari/76425577#76425577).