# Why does the react router Link component not accept children when used as a variable JSX constructor?

Tags: typescript

I can use `Link` as follows with no issues. It accepts children.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to=''>
    {content}
</Link>
```

I can also use a `<button>` the same way.

```
<button>
    {content}
</button>
```

I can conditionally construct a `Link` or `button` with no problems.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyElement = condition ? Link : 'button';

<MyElement />
```

However, once I add children I get an issue.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyElement = condition ? Link : 'button';

<MyElement>
    {content}
</MyElement>
```

```
Type '{ children: MyElement; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

I don't understand how the TS types are working here to not allow children in the variable component.

I am using `react-router-dom` version 5.3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you can explicitly type the MyElement variable using the React.ElementType type from React.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

const MyElement: React.ElementType = condition ? Link : 'button';

<MyElement>
  {content}
</MyElement>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Can you also please provide a link to the documentation for `React.ElementType`? I want to learn more about it, but I didn't find anything online.